# how can I move all lines beginning in 'foobar' to the end of a file?

Tags: string, bash

Say I have a script with a number of lines beginning `foobar`

I would like to move all of the lines to the end of the document while keeping their order

e.g. go from:

```
# There's a Polar Bear
# In our Frigidaire--
foobar['brangelina'] <- 2
# He likes it 'cause it's cold in there.
# With his seat in the meat
foobar['billybob'] <- 1
# And his face in the fish
```

to

```
# There's a Polar Bear
# In our Frigidaire--
# He likes it 'cause it's cold in there.
# With his seat in the meat
# And his face in the fish
foobar['brangelina'] <- 2
foobar['billybob'] <- 1
```

This is as far as I have gotten:

```
grep foobar file.txt > newfile.txt
sed -i 's/foobar//g' foo.txt
cat newfile.txt > foo.txt
```

Comment: Hint: the output file is just all the lines not beginning with foobar, followed by all the lines beginning with foobar. Two grep commands.

Comment: @Amnon thanks for pointing that out. makes sense, but I still am not sure how to say "not" in bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work:

```
sed '/^foobar/{H;$!d;s/.*//};$G;s/\n*//' input_file
```

EDIT: Amended for the corner case when `foobar` is on the last line

Comment: diff shows it is the same as the other two, but the one liner takes it (unless something more awesome appears). It would be great if you could explain what `{H;d};$G;s/\n/` does, for extra credit.

Comment: All lines that don't contain the string `foobar` pass straight through. Those lines that contain `foobar` are appended to the a register called the hold space, then the pattern space (the current line) is deleted. On the last line `$` the hold space (which contains all the foobar lines) is appended to the pattern space, ready to be printed but first an empty line is deleted.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -v ^foobar file.txt > file1.txt
grep ^foobar file.txt > file2.txt
cat file2.txt >> file1.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do:

```
grep -v ^foobar file.txt > tmp1.txt
grep ^foobar file.txt > tmp2.txt
cat tmp1.txt tmp2.txt > newfile.txt
rm tmp1.txt tmp2.txt
```

The `-v` option returns all the lines which **do not** match the given pattern.  The `^` marks the beginning of a line, so `^foobar` matches lines **beginning with** `foobar`.

Comment: @David Because Abe wants to move lines **beginning with** foobar, and `^` marks the beginning of a line.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -v ^foobar file.txt >newfile.txt
grep ^foobar file.txt >>newfile.txt
```

no need for temporary file

Comment: Abe: then please tell me why, because it seems to work fine on my machine

Comment: You have two different output file names.

Comment: LOL, finaly I see that I deserve the -1. Repairing this as well.

Comment: @Dadam now I see your point about not having a temporary file. Thanks

Comment: Not the correct use for grep.. and you cant write to a file your using as input.. thats the whole reason sed has -i switch..

Comment: @WaqasKhan Could you be more specific, please? What's wrong with my grep? Where do I write to an input file?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
vim file.txt -c 'g/^foobar/m$' -c 'wq'
```

The `-c` switch means an Ex command follows, the `g` commands operates on all lines containing the pattern given, and the action is here `m$` which means “move to end of file” (it preserves order). `wq` weans “save and exit vim”.

If this is too slow you can also prevent vim from reading vimrc:

```
vim -u NONE file.txt -c 'g/^foobar/m$' -c 'wq'
```